# Can someone explain this sinc function equation?

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

$ \frac{A}{2}(e^{jω\frac{T}{2}}-e^{-jω\frac{T}{2}})+\frac{A}{2}sinc(\frac{ωT}{4π})(e^{jω\frac{T}{4}}-e^{-jω\frac{T}{4}})=Ajsinc(\frac{ωT}{2π})+Ajsinc^2(\frac{ωT}{4π})$

Answer (score 0):

Probably a typo. You might be looking for [$sine$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Sine_with_a_complex_argument) instead of [$sinc$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). $-$ Then just use
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{jx}-e^{-jx}}{2j}$$

--- rk

Comment: No $\pi$ in the sine formula.

Comment: Right you are indeed, corrected above. But then the $\pi$ in the sinc-arguments of the question won't work either. - A further typo?